# Registering a type with ctor that expects runtime parameters in unityContainer

Tags: c#, unit-testing, unity-container

I'm using a `UnityContainer`.

I want to register in it `AuthService` and `TokenManager`.

`AuthService` has TokenManager as a private memeber.

`TokenManager` has one ctor: `TokenManager(string name, string pass)`

I get these strings from the UI at runtime.

Unity require to register ctor parameters in a config file.

I have thought

- to create a ctor: `AuthService(TokenManager  mgr)`

But then how do I add an object (non-primitive) to the `<unity>` node in the config file?

- How can I still use Unity with runtime parameter to `TokenManager` ctor?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My idea:

AuthService will have two ctor - parameterless and `AuthService(bool initFromContainer)`

In test harness I will call  new AuthService(false) and then override the TokenManager

using AuthService_Accessor

Answer (score 0):

Define a factory for `TokenManager` and inject the factory into `AuthService`. Make the factory accept the parameters for username and password.

Injecting a factory works quite well whenever you need to [incorporate runtime parameters](http://kozmic.pl/2010/06/22/how-i-use-inversion-of-control-containers-ndash-pulling-from/). But don't get carried away with that pattern or you might bump into [factory overload](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2011/12/19/FactoryOverload.aspx).